# Samba4.2 & ubuntu 13.10 session setup failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

Tags: ubuntu, samba4, domain-controller

I have ubuntu 13.10 with samba 4.2
I use samba with internal DNS.
My smb.conf

```
# Global parameters
[global]
#       interfaces = 192.168.0.1
        workgroup = BAGCHE
        realm = BAGCHE.RU
        netbios name = GLAFIR-PC
        server role = active directory domain controller
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
        allow dns updates = nonsecure and secure

[netlogon]
        path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol/bagche.ru/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol
        read only = No
[media]
        path = /media
        comment = Media Share
        read only = No
```

My DNS answer:

```
root@glafir-pc:/usr/local/samba/etc# host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.bagche.ru.
_ldap._tcp.bagche.ru has SRV record 0 100 389 glafir-pc.bagche.ru.
root@glafir-pc:/usr/local/samba/etc# host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.bagche.ru.
_kerberos._udp.bagche.ru has SRV record 0 100 88 glafir-pc.bagche.ru.
root@glafir-pc:/usr/local/samba/etc# host -t A glafir-pc.bagche.ru.
glafir-pc.bagche.ru has address 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
glafir-pc.bagche.ru has address 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
glafir-pc.bagche.ru has address 95.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

/etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = BAGCHE.RU
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

kinit

```
Password for glafir@BAGCHE.RU: 
Warning: Your password will expire in 41 days on Sun Mar 30 07:39:48 2014
```

klist

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: glafir@BAGCHE.RU

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
16.02.2014 09:03:29  16.02.2014 19:03:29  krbtgt/BAGCHE.RU@BAGCHE.RU
        renew until 17.02.2014 09:03:19
```

smbclient -L localhost

```
Enter glafir's password: 
**session setup failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND**
```

How to fix it?
Help me please!!!

Comment: I'm facing the same! now I'll try to downgrade de source to 4.1.4 and recompile. 12 hours working on it , lets me out ouf this wolrd. and increasing all debug levels on logs , brings me nothing. maybe in that old versio doesn't happen. Cheers

Comment: I suggest having a read through of this as it can help you to improve your question http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault